# How can I convert this stacked barplot to a circular plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-bar-chart

I want to convert this stacked barplot to a circular plot in R.

[image]

but the script [here](https://r-graph-gallery.com/299-circular-stacked-barplot.html) is just for grouped bar plots (as you can see at the center of the circle: A,B,C,D).

How can I convert this stacked barplot to a circular plot?

Here is my data:

```
   dput(df.bar)
structure(list(`Gene name` = c("Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene3", "Gene3", 
"Gene3", "Gene4", "Gene4", "Gene4", "Gene4", "Gene5", "Gene5", 
"Gene5", "Gene5", "Gene6", "Gene6", "Gene6", "Gene6", "Gene7", 
"Gene7", "Gene7", "Gene7", "Gene8", "Gene8", "Gene8", "Gene8", 
"Gene9", "Gene9", "Gene9", "Gene9", "Gene10", "Gene10", "Gene10", 
"Gene10", "Gene11", "Gene11", "Gene11", "Gene11", "Gene12", "Gene12", 
"Gene12", "Gene12", "Gene13", "Gene13", "Gene13", "Gene13", "Gene14", 
"Gene14", "Gene14", "Gene14", "Gene15", "Gene15", "Gene15", "Gene15", 
"Gene16", "Gene16", "Gene16", "Gene16"), `Alteration Frequency` = c(0, 
0.090991811, 2.183803458, 0.636942675, 0, 0.181983621, 1.091901729, 
0.363967243, 0, 0.454959054, 0.727934486, 0.727934486, 0, 0, 
0.363967243, 0.454959054, 0, 0, 1.364877161, 1.000909918, 0, 
0.272975432, 1.910828025, 0, 0, 0, 1.000909918, 0.727934486, 
0.090991811, 0.454959054, 14.83166515, 0.727934486, 0, 0, 1.18289354, 
0.363967243, 0, 0, 0.818926297, 0.363967243, 0, 0, 4.458598726, 
1.000909918, 0, 0, 0.636942675, 0.181983621, 0, 0, 0.636942675, 
0.181983621, 0.090991811, 0, 9.099181074, 0.363967243, 0, 0.181983621, 
0.363967243, 0.272975432, 0, 0.272975432, 0.181983621, 0.363967243
), `Alteration Type` = c("Multiple Alteration", "Deep deletion", 
"Amplification", "Point mutation", "Multiple Alteration", "Deep deletion", 
"Amplification", "Point mutation", "Multiple Alteration", "Deep deletion", 
"Amplification", "Point mutation", "Multiple Alteration", "Deep deletion", 
"Amplification", "Point mutation", "Multiple Alteration", "Deep deletion", 
"Amplification", "Point mutation", "Multiple Alteration", "Deep deletion", 
"Amplification", "Point mutation", "Multiple Alteration", "Deep deletion", 
"Amplification", "Point mutation", "Multiple Alteration", "Deep deletion", 
"Amplification", "Point mutation", "Multiple Alteration", "Deep deletion", 
"Amplification", "Point mutation", "Multiple Alteration", "Deep deletion", 
"Amplification", "Point mutation", "Multiple Alteration", "Deep deletion", 
"Amplification", "Point mutation", "Multiple Alteration", "Deep deletion", 
"Amplification", "Point mutation", "Multiple Alteration", "Deep deletion", 
"Amplification", "Point mutation", "Multiple Alteration", "Deep deletion", 
"Amplification", "Point mutation", "Multiple Alteration", "Deep deletion", 
"Amplification", "Point mutation", "Multiple Alteration", "Deep deletion", 
"Amplification", "Point mutation")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-64L))
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(geomtextpath)

ggplot(df.bar, aes(x = factor(`Gene name`, unique(`Gene name`)), 
                   y = `Alteration Frequency`, 
                   fill = `Alteration Type`)) +
  annotate('textsegment', label = c("0", "1", "2"), x = c(-Inf, -Inf, -Inf), 
           xend = c(Inf, Inf, Inf), y = c(0, 1, 2), yend = c(0, 1, 2),
         linewidth = 0.2, linecolour = 'gray50', hjust = 0.015) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(0.5, 1.5), size = 0.2, colour = 'gray75') +
  geom_col(width = 0.5, position = position_stack(), alpha = 0.8) +
  coord_polar(start = -pi/30) +
  ylim(c(-2, 2.2)) +
  annotate('segment', x = 1:16, xend = 1:16, y = rep(-1, 16),
           yend = rep(-0.6, 16), color = 'gray75') +
  annotate('text', x = 0, y = -2, label = 'Gene', size = 8,
           color = 'gray50') +
  annotate('textsegment', label = 1:16, 
           x = -0.3 + 1:16, xend = 0.3 + 1:16, y = rep(-0.1, 16), 
           yend = rep(-0.1, 16), vjust = 1.2, color = 'gray50') +
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_brewer("Alteration Type", palette = 'Set2') +
  labs(title = 'Alteration Frequency') +
  theme(plot.title.position = 'panel',
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = -10))
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Allan, your comments are super helpful, thank you so much. Indeed, I have 16 genes and I think it is better to draw stacked barplots. I would appreciate it if you could help me to make it.

Comment: @zahraabdi in that case, could you please post the data for all 16 genes? If you edit your question to include the output from `dput(df.bar)` I can have a look for you. Thanks.